# How to define a predicate in SMT-LIB

Tags: predicate, smt

How would I define a predicate such as `even: Int -> Bool`, which takes an integer and outputs whether it is even or not?

I tried something like

```
(set-logic AUFNIRA)
(declare-fun even (Int) Bool)
```

I want to know how to declare, for example, that `even(2)` is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are roughly 3 ways to do this.

1. You can use the interpreted predicate [(_ divisible
   2)](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/Ints.smt2).

   ```
   (assert ((_ divisible 2) 6))
   ```

   You can use a define-fun to capture even exactly.

   ```
   (define-fun even ((x Int)) Bool ((_ divisible 2) x))
   ```

   Note that this may not be in your logic of choice, say [QF_LIA](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics/QF_LIA.smt2).
2. You can declare an uninterpreted predicate, and define
   its semantics pointwise.

   ```
   (declare-fun even (Int) Bool)
   (assert (even 2))
   (assert (not (even 3)))
   ```
3. You can declare an uninterpreted predicate and define
   its semantics via quantifiers.

   ```
   (declare-fun even (Int) Bool)
   (assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (even x) (exists ((y Int)) (= x (* 2 y))))))
   ```